# Command errored out with exit status 1: Python setup.py [...] When trying to install Pysam

Tags: python, pip, pysam

I have been troubleshooting this issue for several days now and have had to draw the conclusion that i need help from you guys!

Info:
Python version: 3.8.2
Pip version: 20.0.2

Updated 
Setuptools
Setuptools wheel
Python-language-server

Installing module using pip with following commands
python -m pip install pysam
or
python -m pip install C:\Users\NDSNIVE\Downloads\pysam-master.zip

**Full error code**

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\program files\python38\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NDSNIVE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NDSNIVE\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\NDSNIVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\pip-egg-info'
     cwd: C:\Users\NDSNIVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\
Complete output (23 lines):
# pysam: cython is available - using cythonize if necessary
# pysam: htslib mode is shared
# pysam: HTSLIB_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=None
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\NDSNIVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\setup.py", line 241, in <module>
    htslib_make_options = run_make_print_config()
  File "C:\Users\NDSNIVE\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-_mdk7oi0\setup.py", line 68, in run_make_print_config
    stdout = subprocess.check_output(["make", "-s", "print-config"])
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 411, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 489, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "c:\program files\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Den angivne fil blev ikke fundet
# pysam: htslib configure options: None
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Please add the full error out put to the question **as code-formatted text**, no screenshots.

Comment: use this code installing , `pip install C:\Users\NDSNIVE\Downloads\pysam-master.zip`

Comment: @PyMatFlow - Did not work, provided me with the same error message (plus.."WARNING:  pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper [...]". I have added the entire error code as code-formatted text, thank you Klaus

Comment: update pip to work

Comment: @ PyMatFlow As stated in the post i am already running the latest edition of pip, 20.0.2

Answer (score 0):

`pysam` is only compatible with these operating systems (from [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/pysam/)), so not windows:

> Operating System
>
> ```
> MacOS
> POSIX
> Unix
> ```